# Reverse Y axis in LazyHighCharts and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a question, how can I reverse y axis in LazyHighCharts and Rails? I tried to add:

f.options[:yAxis][:reverse] = true

but it don't work. Any solutions?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about `LazyHighCharts` but if it parrots the same parameters as the [Highcharts api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversed) it would be:

```
f.options[:yAxis][:reversed] = true
```

Note the **d** on the `:reversed`.

Comment: thanks, It works right now. I don't know why I don't find it. Regards.